# Bind to HIGH_VALUE

Tags: wpf, oracle, type-conversion, database-partitioning

Using VB.NET I am putting the results of the SQL Query:

`select TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE from user_tab_partitions WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'LXA%' OR TABLE_NAME LIKE 'LNX%'`

into a `DataTable` (via an `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader`).

I am then binding a WPF `DataGrid` to the contents of that table, using `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static l:Handlers.DatabaseHandler}, Path=DBPartitionData}"` on the table and `Binding="{Binding TABLE_NAME}"` on the `DataGridTextColumn`.

This works fine for `TABLE_NAME` and `PARTITION_NAME`, but `HIGH_VALUE` doesn't display. The SQL query works fine in Oracle SQL Developer.

Looking around, it seems that `HIGH_VALUE` is stored in some internal oracle format - so my question is:

How do I bind to that value? Or even use it? Which of the `Oracle.DataAccess.Types` can I use (if any), or if all else fails, how can I display the value directly without parsing it? ToString() on the returned objects seems to give just empty strings.

There's [plenty](https://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/decoding-high_value-and-low_value/) of [sites](https://chandlerdba.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/decoding-dba_tab_columns-high_value-and-low_value/) that explain how to get the value using pl/SQL, but nothing for how to display it as (any sort of) a string in .NET.

Thanks for your help.

--edit--

I can't debug and see what's in the returned datatable from the sql query, because I don't have a version of Oracle with partitioning on my local machine - only on the test machine (which doesn't have VS). But, putting in some logging, it seems that: the returned HIGH_VALUE values are non-null and ToString() on them returns a zero-length value.

Comment: I think [this is relevant](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featData.htm#i1007197) but I can't test it; I'm not sure what it means by "The LONG or LONG RAW data is fetched when the typed accessor method is explicitly invoked for the LONG or LONG RAW column" though. So I'm not sure if changing the fetch value will make an immediate difference, or if you need an extra step.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for taking time to understand my rambling question and provide an answer that works :D If you write it up as an answer (I needed to set it to -1), then I'll mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS.HIGH_VALUE` column is a `LONG`, which Oracle deprecated a long time ago but still use internally. They are a bit of a pain to work with, which is why they tell everyone else to use LOBs instead.

From the [OracleDataReader documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featData.htm#i1007197):

> By default, InitialLONGFetchSize is set to 0. In this case, ODP.NET does not fetch any LONG or LONG RAW column data during the Read method invocations on the OracleDataReader object.

Although it goes on to mention explicitly invoking a typed accessor method, it also then says:

> To be able to fetch the entire LONG or LONG RAW data without having a primary key column, a ROWID, or unique columns in the select list, set the size of the InitialLONGFetchSize property on the OracleCommand object to equal or greater than the number of characters or bytes needed to be retrieved.

and

> By setting InitialLONGFetchSize to -1, it is possible to fetch the entire LONG or LONG RAW data from the database for a select query, without requiring a primary key, ROWID, or unique column in the select list.

In your case it seems that just changing the `InitialLONGFetchSize` to -1 solves your problem and causes the entire value to be retrieved and displayed.